# JMeter performance plugin report always showing 100% of errors on 200 success response code

Tags: plugins, jenkins, automation, continuous-integration, jmeter

After the build is completed, in the performance Trend report error column displays 100% error whereas the HTTP Response code is 200 (Successful)

**Expected Result:** That should be 0% error in error column.

We have **performance plugin 1.13** in **jenkins 1.607**

[image]

**My .jtl file contains:**

```
1434631428652,2082,Deactivate_Enrollee,200,OK,setUp Thread Group 1-1,text,true,536,2073
1434631430748,574,Activate_Enrollee,200,OK,setUp Thread Group 1-1,text,true,536,574
1434631431323,315,User_Status,200,OK,setUp Thread Group 1-1,text,true,1317,315
1434631431711,1,Debug Sampler,200,OK,setUp Thread Group 1-1,text,true,807,0
```

**Console output:**

```
Started by user anonymous
Building in workspace /results/jtls
Performance: Percentage of errors greater or equal than 0% sets the build as unstable
Performance: Percentage of errors greater or equal than 0% sets the build as failure
Performance: Recording JMeter reports '*.jtl'
Performance: Parsing JMeter report file APITest_JMeter.jtl
Performance: File APITest_JMeter.jtl reported 100.0% of errors [FAILURE]. Build status is: FAILURE
Build step 'Publish Performance test result report' changed build result to FAILURE
Finished: FAILURE
```

Can anyone solve this for Jenkins?

Comment: any feedback on my answer ? if it was helpful it should be accepted and possibly upvoted so that it's helpful to others

Comment: I cant update my jtl file every time manually, that is auto created by jenkins after executing the tests. Even I also tried this by grabbing latest code of performance plugin from git repo. In order to resolve this issue, I moved my reports to xml from jtl for 100% error issues and for URI issue I downgraded my performance plugin version to 1.11. Thanks.

Comment: how is your csv file generated, that's not standard jmeter output as I explained. Can you show content of your jmeter.properties and user.properties I think I know now where your problem comes from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that it is due to a defect in Performance Plugin version 1.13.

You may use Performance Plugin version 1.9 or below and let us know if this resolves your issue.

Comment: 1.9 is not supporting Jenkins 1.607 so I moved on 1.11 that works fine, but before this .. in order to resolve 100% error issues I moved on xml instead of jtl.

Answer (score 1):

Your jtl file is wrong for the plugin from :

- https://github.com/jenkinsci/performance-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/hudson/plugins/performance/JMeterCsvParser.java#L157

So this leads to failure of parsing this value to a boolean by this code:

> sample.setSuccessful(Boolean.valueOf(values[successIdx]));

I think your configuration of saveservice is not well suited for the plugin, you should set:

> jmeter.save.saveservice.response_message=false

Comment: I tried to grab the latest code from git repo but unfortunately that didnt resolve this issue. So I just downgraded performance plugin to 1.11 and using xml instead of jtl for URI issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be facing well-known critical bug [28426](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-28426) of [Performance Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Performance+Plugin).

Comment: Yes that is reported one .. but i resolved 100% error issue by moving to xml from jtl ..